# how to make dynamic categories in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm novice in backends but I really want to do this in some automatic way, the product pages I have to make are so many
hard to handle when I have to edit codes in the future

navigation menu

```
<ul class="category">

  <li>

    <a href="productsListPage.php">All Products</a>

    <ul class="subCategory">
      <li><a href="productsListPage.php" id="catA">Category A</a></li>
      <li><a href="productsListPage.php" id="catB">Category B</a></li>
      <li><a href="productsListPage.php" id="catC">Category C</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

productsListPage.php

```
<div class="AAA" id="pr1">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>
<div class="AAA" id="pr2">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>

<div class="BBB" id="pr3">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>
<div class="BBB" id="pr4">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>

<div class="CCC" id="pr5">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>
<div class="CCC" id="pr6">
  <a href="productView.php"></a>
</div>
```

I want to make the links dynamically
and generate pages for each products automatically
like this I think?

```
<!--navigation menu-->

<ul class="category">

  <li>

    <a href="productsListPage.php">All Products</a>
    <!--shows all products-->

    <ul class="subCategory">

      <li><a href="productsListPage.php?id=catA" id="catA">Category A</a></li>
      <!--only shows products in category A-->

      <li><a href="productsListPage.php?id=catB" id="catB">Category B</a></li>
      <!--only shows products in category B-->

      <li><a href="productsListPage.php?id=catC" id="catC">Category C</a></li>
      <!--only shows products in category C-->

    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>





<!--productsListPage.php-->

<div class="AAA" id="pr1">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr1"></a>
</div>
<div class="AAA" id="pr2">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr2"></a>
</div>
<!--products in category A-->

<div class="BBB" id="pr3">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr3"></a>
</div>
<div class="BBB" id="pr4">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr4"></a>
</div>
<!--products in category B-->

<div class="CCC" id="pr5">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr5"></a>
</div>
<div class="CCC" id="pr6">
  <a href="productView.php?id=pr6"></a>
</div>
<!--products in category C-->
```

and I wonder how can I link(put) certain products into certain categories

I got Bitnami WAMP installed
and I've set my PhpMyAdmin like this
database: products
ㄴ table: cat
ㄴ columns: categA, categB, categC

Comment: Can you please give us more info how you are doing this now, like currently are you using static pages?

Comment: yes I am using static pages for now. just started php to include other php pages for layout.. then I started doing these product pages and thought I'm going to need more than php include

Answer (score 0):

You should start by changing the database structure, fixing column name by categories is the start of your problem
You may start with creating two column (type = [A, B, C], name)

```
database: products
ㄴ table: cat
ㄴ columns: type, name
```

Then you can retrieve categories by SQL and display your list (something like this):

```
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    <a href="productsListPage.php">All Products</a>
    <ul class="subCategory">
      <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <li><a href="productsListPage.php?id=cat<?= $category['type'] ?>" id="catA">Category <?= $category['type'] ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
Table  for category:-  id int(10),name varchar(30)

```
<ul class="category">

  <li>

    <a href="productsListPage.php">All Products</a>
    <!--shows all products-->

    <ul class="subCategory"

<?php>
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ';  
$retval=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){

echo '<li><a href="productsListPage.php?id='.$row["id"].' " id="'.$row["id"].' ">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
}
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```